# Paginating mysql data using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I borrow this code from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=takddjxhWT0

But when I run this code manually, the data that I get into the database doesn't change when I click the other page number. What do you think is the best code in order to run code this manually?

Any comment will help, thanks.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("steer");

$page=(isset($_GET["page"]));

if($page=="" || $page=="1")
{
$page1=0;
}
else 
{
$page1=($page*12)-5;
}

$res=mysql_query("select * from studtut LIMIT $page1,5");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{

echo $row["id"]." ".$row["name"];
echo "<br>";

}

$res1=mysql_query("select * from studtut");
$cou=mysql_num_rows($res1);

$a=$cou/5;
$a=ceil($a);
    echo "<br>"; 
    echo "<br>";
        for($b=1;$b<=$a;$b++){

        ?><a href="paging.php?=<?php echo $b; ?>" style="text-decoration:none "><?php echo $b; " " ?></a> <?php

        }


?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `the data that I get into the database doesn't change` Why  Database would change ?? You just fired SELECT query No t insert,update,delete

Comment: **MySQL is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, MySQLi or PDO_MySQL should be used.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<a href="paging.php?page=<?php echo $b; ?>"` .Why ?

Because you access `$_GET["page"]` as Query string in PHP file . So it should be set in Link so that it doesnt become Blank in PHP file.

In your case `$page` is always Blank as its not defined . Turn `error_reporting(E_ALL)` always in Development mode to see errors,warnings,notices.

Comment: Thanks user4035 and jQuery.PHP.Magento.com !. . it HELPS a LOT! (^_^). .

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `page` variable. This:

```
<a href="paging.php?=<?php echo $b; ?>"
```

Must be changed to this:

```
<a href="paging.php?page=<?php echo $b; ?>"
```

Also when you get the variable, you must assign it's value. And not the value, returned by isset function:

```
$page= isset($_GET["page"]) ? $_GET["page"] : 1;
```

Comment: And always be aware, that you can't trust a user! http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

Comment: @theColaKid He calculated `$page1` variable inside the code. I don't think, there can be an SQL injection here. But extra validation will be good.